# how to access routing controller form main to nested controller in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is my routing code:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', 'main')
    .when('/books','main.book')
    .segment('main', {
        templateUrl:'templates/main.html',
        controller:MainCtrl})
    .within()
        .segment('book', {
            templateUrl:'templates/book.html',
            controller:BookCtrl
        })
```

These are the controllers:

```
function Mainctrl()
{


},

function Bookctrl($http,$cacheFactory)
{
    var bookCache = $cacheFactory('Books');
   var book = bookCache.get("BookName");
    if(!book){
                  alert("first time");
        var data=[{"name":"1"},{"name":"2"},{"name":"3"}];

       bookCache.put("BookName",data);

  } else {

          alert("second time");
          alert(book);
  }

}
```

First I am loading `main.html` page. It has one nested view and has one button (Book). When the user clicks on that button I am just loading `book.html` into that nested view and then within the `BookCtrl` function I am sending a request to the server to get the data from the server. I am getting a response and I have displayed all data that is working fine. But when I click on that button each time a request is sent to server. So instead of that I have planned to keep all of the data in an array when I click the first time. I have tried by using the above code but when I click for the first time the array is empty so it is pushing data into the array but when I click again it is not showing anything. That means I am not getting any alert. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about how to cache items and use them between controllers use [cacheFactory](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24cacheFactory)

```
var bookCache = $cacheFactory('Books');
...
var book = bookCache.get("BookName")
//book will be undefined if not cached
if(!book){
   //do request to get book
    $http.getJSON(url,function(data)
    {
       var book = {name:data.name,isbn:data.isbn};
       //then save it
       bookCache.put("BookName",);
       //do something with it
       showBook(book);
    });
} else {
  //book was cached, do something with it
  showBook(book);
}
```

you can then access the cache in the other controllers by getting the cache object

```
function Mainctrl() {
   //Will be undefined if it hasnt been created yet.
   var bookCache = $cacheFactory.get('Books');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ...i have tried your code ....when i click first time it is coming into if condition but when i click on second time i am not getting any alert....please see my above code ...i have used your $cacheFactory concept instead of array concept

Comment: @silvesterprabu, well if you are not getting either of the alerts then you your Bookctrl isnt even being executed

Comment: ok...but when i click on first time it is executed , second time also executed but it is not checking that if statement becz i have put one alert before of that if statement.....

Comment: edit your question to show how you implemented the cacheFactory.

Comment: i am using array as a value instead of sending request to server